# If any language accpeted by a finite automata is regular then why do we convert to a DFA every time we need to prove a language as regular?

Tags: computational-mathematics, automata

Theory of computation question. since all the automatas we have studied are finite then why do we convert to DFAs while proving any theorems

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the only automata you have studied were finite, then you are still a beginner in theory of computation. The reason all your proofs involve a DFA is probably just that you have not advanced to any questions where your instructor thinks it is necessary or desirable to use a different model.

Comment: Finding a $DFA$ which accepts a language suffices to prove that it is regular, so why not do that? What more ways of proving a language is regular do  you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

We don't always convert to a DFA.  That is just one method to prove that a language is regular.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755 for a range of methods.